# Parsing a JSON with array value

Tags: java, json

I have a json response like {"xyz": ["a","b","c"]}.
I am trying to get the values a, b, c as string using [JsonObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/index.html?org/json/JSONObject.html) and [JsonArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/index.html?org/json/JSONObject.html) classes.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you may need to do something like below

```
JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject(JSON_OBJECT); 
JSONArray xyz_array= myjson.getJSONArray("xyz");
```

and iterate over the xyz_array to get each object in the array.